# Create certificate for openssl_pkcs7_sign in php

Tags: php, openssl

Regarding to the documentation on signing emails with pkcs7 in php I have to use a prior generated certificate.

What is the command to exactly generated the necessary files for this example in openssl?
http://www.php.net/manual/it/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php

```
<?php
// the message you want to sign so that recipient can be sure it was you that
// sent it
$data = <<<EOD

You have my authorization to spend $10,000 on dinner expenses.

The CEO
EOD;
// save message to file
$fp = fopen("msg.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
// encrypt it
if (openssl_pkcs7_sign("msg.txt", "signed.txt", "mycert.pem",
    array("file://mycert.pem", "mypassphrase"),
    array("To" => "joes@example.com", // keyed syntax
          "From: HQ <ceo@example.com>", // indexed syntax
          "Subject" => "Eyes only")
    )) {
    // message signed - send it!
    exec(ini_get("sendmail_path") . " < signed.txt");
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit 1:

```
$prepend = "file:/";
openssl_pkcs7_sign($prepend . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/text.txt",
$prepend . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/enc.txt",
$prepend . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/selfcert.pem",
array($prepend . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/enc_key.pem", "123456"),
$headers);
```

I generated the cert file with the command

```
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout enc_key.pem -out selfcert.pem
```

Still get the error:

Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting private key in ...

Edit 2: added prepend

Maybe it has something to do with the "preprend"? Im really not sure if the problem is either in the file retrieve or the key itself.

Comment: the second argument "signed.txt" is the output file if that's what you're after.

Comment: No, the problem is that im getting errors. Im not sure if if I generated the certfile the right way. I used openssl req -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout enc_key.pem -out selfcert.pem. I  did edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5):

Solved it on my own. The problem was retrieving the keys correctly. 
So for everyone coming onto that problem:

```
$prepend = "file://";
openssl_pkcs7_sign(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/text.txt",
        realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/enc.txt",
        $prepend . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) ."/selfcert.pem",
        array($prepend . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) ."/enc_key.pem", "123456"), $headers);
```